# Delete tables only if days more than n days in Teradata

Tags: unix, teradata

Want to delete tables only if days more than n days in teradata tables

DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE CAST(LOAD_DT AS DATE) < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY;

Here LOAD_DT  is a column name in table_A when the data was inserted in the table_A

LOAD_DT format - 4/10/2018  12:57:00

Answer (score 0):

Teradata uses Standard SQL's CURRENT_DATE instead of NOW:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE CAST(LOAD_DT AS DATE) < CURRENT_DATE - 60;
```